# I tried to post my app on the play store but she says it's debug

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-build

I have been posting my app to playstore but it does not accept my apk because it says that it is debuggable even after I take phonegap build debug mode and compile a new apk over there why does this happen?

Comment: you need to sign your app first, then push to playstore

Answer (score 0):

Sign your apk if not signed and try again

[How to create signed android apk with Apache Cordova](http://memebook.org/id=2)

[How To Sign PhoneGap Build Apps](http://memebook.org/tutorials/how-to-sign-phonegap-build-apps/)